# Get version database ormlite

Tags: android, database, ormlite

I use a database in ormlite. I would like to get the version of my database in the  Activity, but I don't know in wich table is saving the version.

Anybody know how can I get the version of the database? I have looked for in the manuals but I haven't found it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the database version number managed by the Android OS then you will know what the number is because otherwise you will get a call to [`onUpgrade(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29).

If your `onUpgrade(...)` method is called, you know what the number is because you get the old version and the new version numbers.  If you *didn't* get the call then you know that the version number you set in your database helper and was passed up to the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class corresponds to the one in the Android's storage.

Here's a sample of code from a typical [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) `DatabaseHelper` class:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
...

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);
}
...

/**
 * This is called when your application is upgraded and it has a higher version 
 * number. This allows you to adjust the various data to match the new version
 * number.
 */
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource,
    int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

in onCreate write this code

```
int version = getHelper().getReadableDatabase().getVersion();
```

hope this help :)

Comment: It will throw the exception because onUpgrade is made only by calling getWritableDatabase()

Comment: So easiest way is to remember version in sharedPrefs